# Change cell colour if value changes

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write some VBA to change the colour of the cell if the user changes to a different value on a particular sheet.

Every month the user will make changes to the same sheet, for that month. There are certain fields that the user will change. There is not a list of what the changes could be as it could be anything. We have asked the user to highlight if they make a change to a cell in the Excel sheet. But I would like to write a macro that does this automatically detects. However, if they make a mistake and put the cell back to it's original value (point at which the file was opened) then no highlight required.

I have this code to change the colour of cell if the value changes

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)

End Sub
```

But how do I change back to no colour, if value is changed back to original value?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You could take a copy of the complete sheet at the point at which you consider the cells to be at their "original value" (workbook open?  when the sheet was originally created?), and then compare the current value to the value of the equivalent cell in the "original" sheet.

Comment: Are there set values or could it be any values that it starts from and could be changed to?

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: problem is how do you know what the original value is, if cell 1 = 10 and cell 2 = 20, if cell 1 changes to 15, then the color changes, how do you remember that the original value was 10 when the value is now 15, so you have to have some way to store the original data

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you may use:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rngCell As Range
    
    Set rngCell = Sheets(3).Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
    
    If IsEmpty(rngCell) Then
        rngCell = Target
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)
    Else
        If rngCell = Target Then
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(120, 120, 120)
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

It sets the value to the third sheet, once it is created and then makes a check if it is changed or not.
`IsEmpty(rngCell)` is the check.

**Edit: Concerning the question for the format**

If you want, try to implement somewhere the following:

```
Private Sub CopyFromAtoB(rngA As Range, rngB As Range)
    
    rngB.Value = rngA.Value
    rngA.Copy
    rngB.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

However, be careful, because you may enter somewhere an endless loop, if you change the value.

The idea not to use a second spreadsheet is not a good one, you need something to compare with. You may save the values in a public `List` or something similar in VBA, but once the spreadsheet is closed or the VBA code is broken, you would lose everything. And this is painful. Thus it is not what I would recommend.

If you want to make it quite professionally use an **SQL database**, this would bring your solution to another level.

Comment: Very nice solution. But that would be nice if that `sheets(3)` disappear after all. And secondly when the cell get back to it's previous color which is `120,120,120` in your example, then **borders disappear too.** How to first detect current border style and then apply it back if the user put the cell back to it's original value ?

Answer (score 1):

As @YowE3K suggested - you could make a copy of the file and use it for comparison.

Add this code to the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit

Public tmpWrkBk As Workbook

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim FSO As Object, TmpFolder As Object
    Dim tmpFileName As String

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set TmpFolder = FSO.GetSpecialFolder(2) 'Set reference to the temp folder.
    tmpFileName = FSO.GetBaseName(ThisWorkbook.Name) & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy hh-mm-ss")

    'Save this file as a temporary file.
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs TmpFolder & Application.PathSeparator & tmpFileName & ".xlsm"

    'Open and hide the temp workbook.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set tmpWrkBk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=TmpFolder & Application.PathSeparator & tmpFileName & ".xlsm", _
            UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
        Workbooks(tmpFileName & ".xlsm").Windows(1).Visible = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tmpTarget As Range
    If Not tmpWrkBk Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'Set reference to same cell in temp workbook and compare values.
        Set tmpTarget = tmpWrkBk.Worksheets(Target.Parent.Name).Range(Target.Address)
        If Target.Value <> tmpTarget Then
            'Value is different, so change the colour.
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB(181, 244, 0)
        Else
            'Value is the same so change the formatting back again.
            tmpTarget.Copy
            Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim tmpFileName As String

    'Close and delete the temp file before closing.
    If Not tmpWrkBk Is Nothing Then
        tmpFileName = tmpWrkBk.FullName
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        tmpWrkBk.Close savechanges:=False
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Kill tmpFileName
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Edit:  You'll note I've put `Application.EnableEvents` when opening and closing the temporary file - this will stop the `Workbook_Open` and `Workbook_Close` events from firing on the temporary file (which would result in some kind of endless loop).